# PowerShell - Parameter Value Tab Expansion for Enum types

Tags: c#, powershell, tabexpansion

Is it possible to implement parameter value tab expansion for `enum` parameter types?

Creating a binary cmdlet with parameter definition:

```
[Parameter]
public SomeEnum Type {get;set;}
```

Is there some way to type:

```
Add-MyThing -Type S<tab>
```

To get:

```
Add-MyThing -Type SomeEnumValue
```

Where:

```
public enum SomeEnum 
{
   SomeEnumValue,
   SomeEnumValue2
}
```

I know it may be possible with overriding the `TabExpansion` function but I was wondering if there was something I could do within my cmdlet to expose this type of functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter parsing and tab-completion are handled by PowerShell.  The only extensibility hook for tab-completion is the TabExpansion function you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into the default `TabExpansion` function I think it is safe to say, by default, this type of funcitonality does not exist in PowerShell. Getting a hold of a beefed up tab expansion function really is the way to go.